# Dismiss a view loaded by a xib when pressing the background in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, popup, xib

I have a function in the ViewController that loads a Xib file when pressing a button, and I show this Xib as a "popup", and I put a grey color in the background as following:

```
var grayBackgroundView = UIView()
var popupView:PopupView?

func showPopupView(){

    self.showGrayBGView(self, grayView: grayBackgroundView)

    popupView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("PopupView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? PopupView
    self.view.addSubview(popupView!)

    popupView?.center = self.view.center
    popupView?.alpha = 0.5
    popupView?.clipsToBounds = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.50, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.popupView?.alpha = 1
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (value:Bool) -> Void in

    }

}
```

Inside this Xib I have created a button that calls to hidePopUpView() function that removes this Xib from the view:

```
func hidePopupView(){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.50, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.grayBackgroundView.alpha = 0
        self.popupView!.alpha = 0

        }) { (value:Bool) -> Void in
            self.popupView!.removeFromSuperview()
            self.grayBackgroundView.removeFromSuperview()

    }

}
```

My question is: is there a way that only if I touch to the grey background and call to hidePopupView() so this Xib gets removed?

Also I have another question. Do you guys think that there is a better way to show a popup-style window considering that I'm going to need to add some input fields and work with them?

[image: App design]

Comment: Have you looked at using a tap gesture?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to implement it. I'm not sure how to tell the app just to call to the function only if you are pressing the background